# Copy multiple cell ranges and paste in chronological order onto next available row on other sheet tab?

Tags: excel, vba

I am using the following code to copy cell ranges from cells on one sheet and paste in chronological order onto another sheet on the next available row.

For some reason if i try to copy multiple cell ranges it will not work, like so:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Address = "$R$71:$U$73" Then
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim copySheet As Worksheet
Dim pasteSheet As Worksheet

Set copySheet = Worksheets("Form")
Set pasteSheet = Worksheets("Total Data")

copySheet.Range("J8").Copy
copySheet.Range("R8").Copy
pasteSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        MsgBox "Something"
    End If

End Sub
```

Please can someone show me where i am going wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't know if I would ever execute a copy to another worksheet based on a cell selection change but try replacing the two copy commands with `copySheet.Range("J8,R8").Copy`.

Comment: @Jeeped Hi, thanks for your suggestion, however this brings up an error - cannot do this to a merged cell?

Comment: Well, your first copy is failing because you cancel the first copy when you start the second. I guess you will just have to Copy, Paste, Copy, Paste.

Comment: @Jeeped but then wouldn't it just paste each range value onto a seperate row? I don't want it to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are only pasting the values so opt for direct value transfer instead.

```
pasteSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = _
    copySheet.Range("J8").Value
pasteSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 1) = _
    copySheet.Range("R8").Value
```

Note the change in the parameters to the [Range.Offset property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840060.aspx). The first finds the last populated row and moves one down. The second finds that cell that just received a value and moves one to the right.